# How to use Sys.Services.AuthenticationService works and what could prevent it from working

Tags: jquery, authentication, asp.net-ajax

My website uses Sys.Services.AuthenticationService in order to do an ajax style login.

Right now it's contained within

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

here's the very beginning of the javascript code... (You can read the full implementation [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/02/18/a-client-side-ajax-login-for-asp-net.aspx))

```
alert("1");
var ssa = Sys.Services.AuthenticationService;
alert("2");
```

The first alert fires and the second one doesn't... any idea of why this wouldn't work? Is there something I need to include in my website like an external resource? Or could it be that it's within the `$(document).ready function`?

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated! If you need any more information just let me know. I'll add updates as I find out more.

**Update:** I just wanted to add a few things...

- I'm running on Asp.Net MVC
- Here is the tutorial I followed -- [Client-side Ajax Login](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/02/18/a-client-side-ajax-login-for-asp-net.aspx)

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't include the MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js files so it couldn't find the Sys.Services.AuthenticationService.

Didn't notice this because in WebForms, asp.net ajax is built right in, there's no need to reference the file.